# Limit point in topological space equivalent definition

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a subset of $X$ then $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in some other point other than $x$ itself. Then Munkres says to say this in another way $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if it belongs to the closure of $A-\{x\}$. How are these two equivalent? How is the closure of $A-\{x\}$ different from the closure of $A$?
If I take $A=(0,1]$, $0$ is the limit point of $A$ but in what way this equivalent way of saying helpful? The closure of $(0,1]-\{0\}$ is the same as the closure of $(0,1]$. Taking $A=[0,1]$ doesn’t help either. Can someone give an example where the closure of $A$ and the closure of $A-\{x\}$ is different?

Comment: The equivalence follows from definitions. Here's an example: $A=\{x\}$.

Answer (score 1):

To see Munkres remark note that

> $x$ is in the closure of a set $B$ iff every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $B$.

which might not be his *definition* but he does show it in 17.5(a) (second edition) (he notes after the theorem that he will call an open set containing $x$ a *neighbourhood* of $x$ so it matches with my formulation above).

So applying this to $B = A-\{x\}$ we get that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ iff $x \in \overline{A-\{x\}}$ immediately.

The difference happens in isolated points of $A$, the most trivial case being when $A=\{x\}$ where $A-\{x\}=\emptyset$ so $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Another example in the reals: $A= (0,1) \cup \Bbb Z$, where the only limit points of $A$ are the points of $[0,1]$. If $x <0$ or $x>1$ we can always find a small open interval around $x$ (so a neighbourhood of $x$) that misses $[0,1]$ and has no integers (except maybe $x$ itself).

So e.g. $A-\{2\}$ does not have $2$ in its closure and $A$ does.